# Android ListView has some items exactly same, how distinguish which one is clicked?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a `ListView` in my Android app, which it has some item with exactly same
name. How can distinguish which one is clicked? Is there any solution?
For example, I have retrieved these rows from database:

[image]

How do I send their ID and receive back their ID by selecting the name in `ListView`?
(I just want to display item's name)

Comment: when it gets clicked, it will have unique id in list, you can access it using that

Comment: using its position

Comment: Position is not useful, I do not know which one position it is.

Comment: You have to implement adapters `getView()` method yourself and set tag to each list item with the real ID. When item is clicked you retrieve this original ID. post your code and I'll try to help

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati  How can I access to that unique Id?

Answer (score 2):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
           // use the position to distinguish the view clicked
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Alireza .. look at his Answer, In parameters of `onItemClick` there's in position, and long id... you can access unique id with that. it starts from 0 to end. If you press number 5th element it will give you 4th position. hope u get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

With the position is:

```
plansList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int intPosition = position;
            String clickedValue = plansList.getItemAtPosition(intPosition).toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] locations = {"russia", "ukraine", "brazil"};
locationList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(locations));
search_listview_result = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_listview_result);
searchResultListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, locationList);
search_listview_result.setAdapter(searchResultListViewAdapter);
search_listview_result.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SelectedLocation", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("Name", locationList.get(position));
            editor.putString("Lat", String.valueOf(locationLatList.get(position)));
            editor.putString("Long", String.valueOf(locationLongList.get(position)));
            editor.commit();

            finish();
        }
    });
```